# How can I force URL of a custom post type archive to use a page template?

Tags: templates, custom-post-type-archives

I have the following custom post type:

```
if ( $args->has_archive ) {
    $archive_slug = $args->has_archive === true ? $args->rewrite['slug'] : $args->has_archive;
    if ( $args->rewrite['with_front'] )
        $archive_slug = substr( $wp_rewrite->front, 1 ) . $archive_slug;
    else
        $archive_slug = $wp_rewrite->root . $archive_slug;


register_post_type( 'jobs',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Jobs' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Job' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
        'has_archive' => $archive_slug,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'revisions','author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attribute' ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'jobs', 'with_front' => true),
            'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category'),
            'can_export' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        //'capability_type'=>'jobs',
        //'capabilities' => array(
        //  'read_post' => 'read_jobs'
        //),
        )
    );
```

Right now, it is using the template `archive-jobs.php` (WordPress' default template system). Now, the thing I want to do it to use a template called `jobs-page.php` for the url `mysite.com/jobs` but that's not possible because WordPress automatically catches that `/jobs` part and redirects it to the archive template.
I tried doing this `'has_archive' => false,` but then WordPress uses `archive.php` for the `mysite.com/jobs`.

What's the best way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass a string for `has_archive`. That string will be used as archive URL.

So in your registration code use:

```
'has_archive' => 'jobs'
```

From the `register_post_type()` declaration in WordPress core:

```
if ( $args->has_archive ) {
    $archive_slug = $args->has_archive === true ? $args->rewrite['slug'] : $args->has_archive;
    if ( $args->rewrite['with_front'] )
        $archive_slug = substr( $wp_rewrite->front, 1 ) . $archive_slug;
    else
        $archive_slug = $wp_rewrite->root . $archive_slug;
```

As you can see, `has_archive` is tested for a string. If it is a string, that string will be used. If it is `TRUE` the slug will be used. The string wins.

Comment: Strange, I changed `'has_archive' => 'open-positions'` to WordPress let me use `/jobs` as a page. But `/jobs` is still loading the `archive.php` template and not `jobs-page.php` (which is set in Pages>Jobs).

Comment: @janoChen Try the [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to see which rewrite rules are used for a given URL.

Comment: I ended up changing this: `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'open-positions', 'with_front' => true),` Only that worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: When changing the archive slug. go to settings and RE-save your permalinks. This will rebuild the slugs for your website!

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post, but maybe this will help somebody.

In your archive-my-cpt.php file you can use `get_page_by_path( 'my-page-slug' );` to get the page object you're looking for and go from there. In other words, let the default template load up, then run grab the page data for the page you *want* to display, and spit out that page data in a custom loop.

forgot the codex link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path

I hope that helps somebody.